# Pass Parameter in Ajax URL

Tags: ajax, url, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass parameter in below ajax url

```
function endprogress(){
 $("#surfbar").html("Please wait...");
 var dataString = 'action=validate&t='+adtk; 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'yes_manage.php?view=surf&track='+user_name&, /*this line giving error*/
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg){
                
            }
        });
}
```

above `url` field is giving error `Expected and identifier instead saw ','`
how can I resolve this

Comment: 'yes_manage.php?view=surf&track='+user_name+ '&'+dataString,
or you must change user_name& => user_name

Answer (score 0):

Change user_name& => user_name
look like

```
function endprogress(){
 $("#surfbar").html("Please wait...");
 var dataString = 'action=validate&t='+adtk; 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'yes_manage.php?view=surf&track='+user_name, /*remove & at the end user_name*/
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg){
                
            }
        });
}
```